# How to convert panel data with R so that each observation per ID is saved in one row and still arranged by year?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-preprocessing

I am planning to do a supvervised machine learning project where I use data from a panel (371'503 rows & 20 columns). The goal is to use data from 2002 to 2014. I have now done a first data-preprocessing and the data frame looks like the following in a highly abbreviated form:

```
data_ex_old <- structure(
  list(
    ID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1,
           2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Studyyear = c(
      2002,
      2002,
      2002,
      2004,
      2004,
      2004,
      2006,
      2006,
      2006,
      2008,
      2008,
      2008,
      2010,
      2010,
      2010,
      2012,
      2012,
      2012,
      2014,
      2014,
      2014
    ),
    Gender = c(2, 1, 2, 2, 1,
               2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2),
    Predictor1 = c(
      "6",
      "5",
      "4",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "5",
      "6",
      "4",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA"
    ),
    Predictor2 = c(2,
                   2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1),
    Predictor3 = c(
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "6",
      "0",
      "0",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "0",
      "6",
      "1",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA"
    ),
    Outcome1 = c(
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "0",
      "1",
      "1",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "1",
      "1",
      "0",
      "NA",
      "NA",
      "NA"
    ),
    Outcome2 = c(0, 0, 1, 0,
                 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
  ),
  class = c("tbl_df",
            "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA,-21L)
)
```

So that I can make useful predictions, all obeservations per ID should be in a row (arranged by year). The result should look like this:

```
data_ex_new <-
  structure(
    list(
      ID = c(1, 2, 3),
      Gender = c(2, 1, 2),
      Predictor1_2002 = c(6,
                          5, 4),
      Predictor2_2002 = c(2, 2, 1),
      Predictor3_2002 = c("NA",
                          "NA", "NA"),
      Outcome1_2002 = c("NA", "NA", "NA"),
      Outcome2_2002 = c(0,
                        0, 1),
      Predictor1_2004 = c("NA", "NA", "NA"),
      Predictor2_2004 = c(1,
                          2, 2),
      Predictor3_2004 = c(6, 0, 0),
      Outcome1_2004 = c("NA",
                        "NA", "NA"),
      Outcome2_2004 = c(0, 0, 1),
      Predictor1_2006 = c(5,
                          6, 4),
      Predictor2_2006 = c(1, 2, 2),
      Predictor3_2006 = c("NA",
                          "NA", "NA"),
      Outcome1_2006 = c("NA", "NA", "NA"),
      Outcome2_2006 = c(0,
                        0, 1),
      Predictor1_2008 = c("NA", "NA", "NA"),
      Predictor2_2008 = c(2,
                          2, 1),
      Predictor3_2008 = c(0, 6, 1),
      Outcome1_2008 = c(0, 1,
                        1),
      Outcome2_2008 = c(0, 0, 1),
      Predictor1_2010 = c("NA", "NA",
                          "NA"),
      Predictor2_2010 = c(1, 2, 2),
      Predictor3_2010 = c("NA",
                          "NA", "NA"),
      Outcome1_2010 = c("NA", "NA", "NA"),
      Outcome2_2010 = c(0,
                        0, 0),
      Predictor1_2012 = c("NA", "NA", "NA"),
      Predictor2_2012 = c(2,
                          2, 2),
      Predictor3_2012 = c("NA", "NA", "NA"),
      Outcome1_2012 = c(1,
                        1, 0),
      Outcome2_2012 = c(1, 1, 0),
      Predictor1_2014 = c("NA",
                          "NA", "NA"),
      Predictor2_2014 = c(2, 2, 1),
      Predictor3_2014 = c("NA",
                          "NA", "NA"),
      Outcome1_2014 = c("NA", "NA", "NA"),
      Outcome2_2014 = c(1,
                        1, 1)
    ),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA,-3L)
  )
```

**How can one convert the data with R so that each observation per ID is saved in one row and still arranged by year (see "data_ex_new")?**

I already tried out different dplyr functions like `spread()` to make the data wide. But so far it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does it:

```
data_ex_old %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID, Gender), names_from = Studyyear,
                            values_from = c(starts_with('Predictor'),
                                            starts_with('Outcome'))) 

# A tibble: 3 × 37
# ID Gender Predic…¹ Predi…² Predi…³ Predi…⁴ Predi…⁵ Predi…⁶ Predi…⁷ Predi…⁸ Predi…⁹ Predi…˟ Predi…˟
# <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1      2 6        NA      5       NA      NA      NA      NA            2       1       1       2
# 2     2      1 5        NA      6       NA      NA      NA      NA            2       2       2       2
# 3     3      2 4        NA      4       NA      NA      NA      NA            1       2       2       1
# # … with 24 more variables: Predictor2_2010 <dbl>, Predictor2_2012 <dbl>, Predictor2_2014 <dbl>,
# #   Predictor3_2002 <chr>, Predictor3_2004 <chr>, Predictor3_2006 <chr>, Predictor3_2008 <chr>,
# #   Predictor3_2010 <chr>, Predictor3_2012 <chr>, Predictor3_2014 <chr>, Outcome1_2002 <chr>,
# #   Outcome1_2004 <chr>, Outcome1_2006 <chr>, Outcome1_2008 <chr>, Outcome1_2010 <chr>,
# #   Outcome1_2012 <chr>, Outcome1_2014 <chr>, Outcome2_2002 <dbl>, Outcome2_2004 <dbl>,
# #   Outcome2_2006 <dbl>, Outcome2_2008 <dbl>, Outcome2_2010 <dbl>, Outcome2_2012 <dbl>,
# #   Outcome2_2014 <dbl>, and abbreviated variable names ¹​Predictor1_2002, ²​Predictor1_2004, …
```